# Save Rtf text in Postgresql

Tags: javascript, postgresql, rtf

I need to save something like this RTF text '{\rtf1deff0{\fonttbl' in Postgres. If I try to save like this, it saves only '{'. It looks like I need to replace every backslash with a double backslash. Tried like this `'{\rtf1deff0{\fonttbl'.replace(/\\/g, "\\")` but still getting '{' in database.

```
update cxema_npa.reestr_npa set data = '{\rtf1deff0{\fonttbl' where cxema_npa.reestr_npa.id = 617
```

Comment: Post the actual code. Perhaps you use string concatenation to construct the query string, resulting in SQL injection. Perhaps your programming language uses `\\` as an escape character (most do). If it does, there's no single quote to replace, the escape sequence was already replaced during compilation

Comment: The edits don't help. Post your code. If you use string concatenation to create the query, don't. Use parameterized queries/server-bound parameters (or whatever your data library calls them)

Answer (score 1):

If that SQL statement does not work as you want it to when you type it into an interactive database client, you must have set the configuration parameter `standard_conforming_strings = off`, so that PostgreSQL interprets `\n` as a newline character. Change that parameter to `on`.

If that is not the problem, the problem must be in your (undisclosed) application programming language.